# SQL Server : trigger to disable old records beeing updated - single row update works, multiple fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

The following SQL is working fine for one row updates, but fails on multiple row updates:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_fix
ON mytable
FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF (SELECT f_month FROM inserted) = 99 
       AND (SELECT x_date FROM mytable 
            WHERE data_id IN ((SELECT data_id FROM inserted)))<= DateAdd(yy, -2, GetDate())
    BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Cannot update old records',16,1)
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
          RETURN;
    END
END 
GO
```

Can anyone help me changing the trigger to work for updates affecting multiple rows? Should examine each row beeing updated separately - so if there is an update of 10 rows where one of them should not be updated - just that one will not be updated, other rows will be updated sucessfully..Is that even possible with a trigger (having in mind I can not redefine the queries itself a these origin from large system and such change would be out of scope)? I worry that one query = one transaction..ie. all can be rolled back, or all commited, but.. maybe it is possible..?

Comment: Well, what do you expect to get here: `SELECT f_month FROM inserted` when you have a 20-row insert and `Inserted` contains 20 rows??

Comment: You could do this but you wont be able to raise an error to know something is wrong because as you said, the transaction makes it all or nothing. You could however, insert errors into another table and read that after you are done but that is ugly. I would say, don't use a trigger to validate your data.

Comment: Steve, your comment seems to be the final answer..I absolutely agree that the concept of validating these data within any trigger is more hack, than coding.. also I come to the same point - it seems like it might be easier to log these updates in a separate table using this trigger and than maybe process a wayback update from these logs ..and my final yes - this would be more than ugly.. but..at the moment I am looking for a "quick fix" and that does not have to be necessarily very nice..will see..anyhow, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

Perform the `UPDATE` in the trigger, and add a `WHERE` condition to the update so that only the rows that are new enough get updated.

Then you can use whatever logic you prefer to get the rowcounts of rows that were not updated, and use `RAISERROR` to send a message like "5 rows were not updated due to age" or whatever you want.

Then there is no need to rollback the transaction at all.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it fails.  You have an `=` for a subquery that can return more than one result.

The `if` should look something like this:

```
if (exists (select 1 from inserted where f_month = 99) and
    exists (select 1
            from mytable
            where data_id in (select data_id from inserted) and
                  x_date <= dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
           )
    )
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the same logic, because the two conditions could be on different records.  It is not clear what the exact conditions you want are.

If both conditions need to be on the same record, the:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from mytable
            where data_id in (select data_id from inserted where f_month = 99) and
                  x_date <= dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
           )
    )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - this makes sence and seem to be the rule I was looking for (not tested yet) - after this rule should be  BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Cannot update old records',16,1) 
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         RETURN; END     or anything else to stop updating just this one row? ie. wont the rollback actually cancel all updates in the query?

Comment: Thats why you use an `instead of` trigger. then you have to explcitly insert rows or nothing happens.

Comment: ok, but..how can I let the query let go normally (if it does not fall in to the rule)..as i understand it, using instead of update means, that i have to specify the rule for any update possible..but i do not know which columns are beeing updated by the specific query..or can i specify any "ELSE process normally " ?

Comment: @WebXpert . . . You have to decide on the behavior you want.  If you want to only `update` rows that meet your criterion, then you can do that.  However, either the trigger raises an error and all fail.  Or, it doesn't raise an error.

Comment: @Gordon ... I want to let any query update any rows newer than 2 years, but I want to cancel any updates of rows older than 2 years.. As I understand it so far - the core of the problem is a single query (for exaple update mytable set mycolumn='myvalue' where 1=1) potentitally updating some older and some newer records - in such case I would like to let the newer records beeing updated but the older ones leave without any changes..